# Lighten Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) library for pdf generation

Tags: c++, pdf, chromium-embedded, blink

Since wkhtmltopdf is not using up-to-date version of webkit, I tried to search for another option.

I have found slimer which is a headless browser based on Gecko, and it gives pretty good result but is not really headless and the project is a bit immature.

One option that I want to try is using Chromium Embedded Framework to render pdf. I read the sources and find out it can run headless, and since it's using blink, the result are pretty good and can use recent html/css/javascript features.

One drawback is the size. After compiling I got a libcef.so file of 92mo.

So my question is: *Is there a way to lighten in size compiled binary of CEF for pdf generation ?*
(Except from manually removing all non desired part from source code... Which would be quite long and painfull...)

Comment: Question has been asked a couple of times on `ceforum`

http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11045&p=18509
http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=628&p=2555

Basically it's a non trivial task and would likely take a large amount of time and require a lot of testing. I think this is one of those cases where disk space and bandwidth are much cheaper than the time required.

Comment: You can try http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=146&p=1383#p485

Comment: You can disable features in chromium code which will not be used by your  application.